# When is the projection of an induced fibration trivial on cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $p: E\to B$ be a fibration, and let $f: A\to B$ be a continuous map. In my applications, $E$ and $B$ are finite complexes, but $A$ need not be. Form the pullback
$$
\begin{array}{ccc} W & \to & E \newline
                   q\downarrow & & \downarrow p\newline
                   A & \stackrel{f}{\to} & B.
\end{array}
$$

> Is it possible to give necessary and sufficient conditions, in terms of the ring maps $p^\ast: H^\ast(B)\to H^\ast(E)$ and $f^\ast: H^\ast(B)\to H^\ast(A)$, which ensure that $q^\ast: H^\ast(A)\to H^\ast(W)$ is identically zero?

or, perhaps more ambitious,

> Is it possible to describe $\ker q^\ast$ in terms of $p^\ast$ and $f^\ast$?

**Remarks:** In my situation, $p^\ast: H^\ast(B)\to H^\ast(E)$ is surjective (in fact split surjective). I am willing to use field coefficients, and (begrudgingly) assume that $B$ is simply-connected, if it helps to obtain an answer in terms of the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence. The paper *Homological algebra and the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence* by Larry Smith has some nice collapse results. In particular Corollary 3.5 in part 2 gives an answer to my more ambitious question by showing that $\ker q^\ast$ is the ideal generated by $\operatorname{im} f^\ast$ when certain algebraic conditions are met. The problem is that these conditions are never met when $B$ is a finite complex, which is my main case of interest, since then everything in $H^\ast(B)$ is a zero-divisor.

Comment: Let $F$ denote the common fiber of the two fibration.  The surjectivity of $p^*$ implies that the map $H^*(E)\rightarrow H^*(F)$ is trivial.  On the other hand, if you are lucky the triviality of $q^*$ implies (although this is not always the case) that $H^*(W)$ injects to $H^*(F)$. Basically this depends on the behavior of the EMSS for the fibration $F\rightarrow W\rightarrow A$. Combining these, the map $H^*(E)\rightarrow H^*(W)$ should be 0, more or less.  This would mean that $Im(f^*)$ should be quite small.  Does this get anywhere?

Comment: @user43326: How does the surjectivity of $p^\ast$ imply that $H^\ast(E)\to H^\ast(F)$ is trivial? Can we see this using the EMSS?

Comment: We don't even need the EMSS, the composition $F\rightarrow E\rightarrow B$ is null-homotopic, so it induces a trivial map in homology.  Combining with the surjectivity of $p^*$, you get the result.

Comment: Ah, I see. This observation could be quite useful. As you indicate, to show that $q^\ast=0$ it suffices to show that $H^\ast(W)\to H^\ast(F)$ is injective, and this latter map should be easier to analyse (as an edge homomorphism in a spectral sequence, for example).

Comment: By the way, is $F$ a loop-space, so that we can use the bar spectral sequence instead of Eilenberg-Moore spectral Sequence?

Comment: Yes, it is. How did you know? ;)

Comment: Great!  I think I can start psychic reading now.  So do you know anything on the ring structure of $H_*(F)$?  If it doesn't contain truncated polynomial algebra, the bar spectral sequence should be easy to analyze.  Another thing is that, intuitively, homologicaly speaking the fibration $F\rightarrow E\rightarrow B$ should somehow look like $\Omega Y\times X \rightarrow X\rightarrow Y$, so you would expect $H^*(f)$ to kill the "$H^*(X)$-factor" if you want $H^*(q)$ to be zero.